# PostgreSQL installation error, how to fix?

Tags: postgresql

help, i searched almost everywhere in the internet for this error, but i didn't find anyone with the same type that i got in my computer, i already tried 3 or 4 diferent versions, all with the same error, i'm running in Administrator mode AND i tried to use the Administrator user.
here's the error image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZBK.jpg
and here's what i belive to be  the error log: https://pastebin.com/5phRm5Jp

```
Script stderr:


Configuring PostgreSQL as auto start
Executing C:\PostgreSQL/pgc config pg96 --autostart on
Script exit code: 1

Script output:
 Error running config-pg96

Script stderr:
 usage: usage: config-pg96.py [-h] [--port PORT] [--autostart={on,off}]
                  [--datadir DATADIR] [--logdir LOGDIR]
                  [--svcname SVCNAME]
config-pg96.py: error: argument --autostart: expected one argument

Error running C:\PostgreSQL/pgc config pg96 --autostart on: usage: usage: 
config-pg96.py [-h] [--port PORT] [--autostart={on,off}]
                  [--datadir DATADIR] [--logdir LOGDIR]
                  [--svcname SVCNAME]
config-pg96.py: error: argument --autostart: expected one argument
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 Error running C:\PostgreSQL/pgc config pg96 --autostart on: usage: usage: 
config-pg96.py [-h] [--port PORT] [--autostart={on,off}]
                  [--datadir DATADIR] [--logdir LOGDIR]
                  [--svcname SVCNAME]
config-pg96.py: error: argument --autostart: expected one argument
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Detail the workflow that led to the error message.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install an old version of Postgres. I recommend you install version 10 or 11.